# OAuth 2.0 authentication in RestSharp

Tags: authentication, oauth, restsharp

I am trying to authenticate RESTful service (sabre REST api) using RESTsharp library but i am not able to authenticate it. I am using my Client id and secret. Please tell me how to authenticate using oAuth 2.0 authenticator.

I have tried this code. ( sabre is using OAuth 2.0 authentication )

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.test.sabre.com");
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("myclientid", "myclientsecret");

    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/v1/auth/token", Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + client);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    var content = response.Content;
    ViewBag.R = content;
    return View();
}
```

i got this result

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Credentials are missing or the syntax is not correct"}
```

please tell what i am doing wrong. 
Thanks

Snapshot of Fiddler Comparison of Running code (not with RestSharp) and code using RestSharp is shown

With RestSharp

[image: using RestSharp]
[image: Not using RestSharp]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me like you are adding the Authorization header twice. The [documentation here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Authenticators) says

> The authenticator’s Authenticate method is the very first thing called
>   upon calling RestClient.Execute

Looking at the implementation of HttpBasicAuthenticator, the Authenticate method adds the appropriate header to the request.

So remove the following line from your example:

> request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + client);

Comment: Install Fiddler and check the Authorization header that goes over the line. It should be in the format: "Basic"<space>Base64(username:password)

Comment: I have checked with the Fiddler and the thing is I am getting the header in the same format you described but i think its not doing the Base64 operation because i have compared it with already running code (not with Restsharp client). I have edited my post by added the comparison snapshots of both. please take a look. thnx

Comment: I got the answer. Thnx for telling me to use fiddler. It really helped me. It was not doing the base64 operation on clientId and clientSecret. So I did that manually and code worked like a charm.

Comment: In Fiddler under tools there's a text wizard. You can use it to decode the base64 string and see what is different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first obtain access token from Sabre that you can later use while making rest api calls.
The access token POST request looks like this:

```
POST https://api.test.sabre.com/v2/auth/token 
Authorization: Basic ZVc5MWNtTnNhV1Z1ZEdsazplVzkxY21Oc2FXVnVkSE5sWTNKbGRBPT0=
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
grant_type=client_credentials
```

where the value of Authorization after Basic is the Base64 encoded string based on your clientId and secret
Refer to [Sabre Authentication](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_basics/authentication) on how this string is created

So, in order to get the access token you just need to send a POST request with required header and request parameters and you do not need to use the Authenticator

Comment: I successfully got the Access token using Sabre Authentication guidelines already but i wanted to implement the same thing using Rest Sharp client which is builtin library for that purpose.