# How to authenticate using OAuth 2.0 with `authentication_code` grant flow type from a C# executable?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, oauth, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

I'm working on a C# command line [tool which automates some deployment tasks](https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/docs/managing-external-applications) by sending requests to the API of an on-premise installation (in this specific case [UiPath Orchestrator](https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/reference/api-references)).

I've used until now [bearer token authentication](https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/reference/authenticating), which is being phased-out and need to move to [OAuth 2.0 for authentication on the respective on-premise setup](https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/docs/susing-oauth-for-external-apps#authorization-code).

So far I've found some examples on how to authenticate using OAuth 2.0 with `client_credentials` *grant flow* type and have been able to successfully implement it myself:

- [How do I get an OAuth 2.0 authentication token in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494279/how-do-i-get-an-oauth-2-0-authentication-token-in-c-sharp)
- [OAuth 2.0 authentication in RestSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352153/oauth-2-0-authentication-in-restsharp)

The problem is that in my specific case `client_credentials` *grant flow* type is allowing the user to access too many resources and need to use instead `authorization_code` *grant flow* type, which lets the user access only allowed resources.

Would appreciate some simple/basic code snippets for `authorization_code` *grant flow* type, since so far found only the following examples, which I'm struggling to fully understand and not sure if those are applicable for my specific case:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/hotel-service/code-example-code-grant-flow
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/shopping-content/code-example-authentication-oauth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console apps do interactive logins using the system browser, in the same manner as desktop apps. There are two options to listen for the login response, reflected in these small C# code samples:

- [Loopback](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/NetCoreConsoleClient/src/NetCoreConsoleClient)
- [Private URI Scheme](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/WindowsConsoleSystemBrowser/WindowsConsoleSystemBrowser)

For further info on concepts, and a couple of Node.js apps you can run locally, see my desktop blog posts, starting [here](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/11/desktop-apps-overview/).